# Start a New Game?

Tags: alice-madness-returns

I've played the game in the past, and didn't get very far, and being a new game, I was clunky at it, so I sort of ditched it for a little while. I've since come back to it, and I want to start over, but there's no option to restart the game?

The only options on the main menu are:

- Continue
- Memories
- Extra Content
- Configuration
- Game Manual
- Download Content
- American McGee's Alice: Available Now

Do I have to delete the save file from the Xbox dashboard? Is this a bug or a "feature"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way that the save system works only allows for one save at a time. So if you want a *completely fresh start*; yes, you will have to delete the save file.

However, once a Chapter has been completed, you can go back and play through again to get anything you may have missed, like pig snouts or memories, etc.

Alternatively, when you beat the game, you can enter New Game+, which carries over all your dresses, teeth, weapon upgrades, memories, bottles, snouts, and radula rooms.